# CRUD в laravel

Tags: laravel, php, crud

Уже более 3 лет пишем на Codeigniter, и к сегодняшнему дню он ужасно устарел. Сейчас потихоньку переходим на Laravel, не хватает crud генератора, который был в CI http://www.grocerycrud.com , чтобы быстро генерить админку. Подскажите, есть ли такое в laravel?

Comment: Кто то сможет помочь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть много Пакетов для Ларавел с CRUD.

1. [Cruddy](https://github.com/cruddy/cruddy) очень хорошая и можно изменить под свои нужды, интеграция с Sentry Cartalyst для прав доступа.
2. Frozennode Administrator Не хуже чем Cruddy.
3. SleepingOwl Admin

Есть ещё много других которые поддерживают как 3.0, 4.2 и Laravel 5

Answer (score 0):

В документации Laravel всё есть: [RESTful Resource Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) и там же как их создавать artisan'ом.

Comment: Это совсем не то.

Comment: Вангую, что, значит, вы хотели ещё и генерирование фронтендовых форм. Ищите от сторонних разработчиков.

Буквальный ответ на ваш вопрос: в самом Laravel такого **нет**.

Comment: да то, что в самом Laravel  нет, это понятно, я про сторонние  разработки и спрашиваю.

Answer (score 0):

С коробки в Laravel такого нет. Да и не нужно в принципе. Написать нужный CRUD не составляет особого труда. Один раз набросали примерный контроллер, модель и вид, а дальше модифицируйте.
Мне наоборот нравится, что нельзя генерировать сразу админку, так как понимаешь, что пишешь, и можешь легко всё подогнать под свои нужды.